# Can elements be "Made" or "Cloned"?

Tags: atomic-physics

So when I came across this question I began thinking, if out of everything how does so much come out of an atom. Like for example the elements, Au (gold) is all over the world but it is not being "created" at the same rate as we are mining it. If Gold is composed of one atom then how do more atoms of gold appear without making a compound.

Do atoms clone, or reproduce, themselves over time? Or are they just there?

I have read up on several sources and I can't seem to find exactly anything on this, however, a link below stated that gold is created from a stars super-nova, but Most stars retain mostly helium and hydrogen. If those supercharged particles are heated and shot out into the vacuum how would the form a single atom element? Please feel free to edit my question if you need to and correct me on my thinking.

https://www.sbcgold.com/blog/how-is-gold-formed-and-where-does-it-come-from/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you consider the universe, atoms are being produced constantly. All elements but hydrogen and helium are produced in supernovae.  All gold on earth, and in the universe, was created this way. The different elements got deposited on earth when the earth would pass thru a supernova remnant or if a meteor hit the earth. This may seem like a slow process. Well, it is, but the earth has had over 4.5 billion years to collect these elements.

Some elements are slowly being created on earth thru radioactive decay. Some naturally occurring elements are radioactive and create other elements by undergoing a nuclear decay. This reduces the amount of the parent nucleus and increases the amount of the daughter.  This is a relatively extremely slow process.